# "Dual" of a CP map

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, complete-positivity

Let $M,N$ be von Neumann algebras, and let $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ be a normal completely positive map.  I am interested in conditions when there is a "dual" normal completely positive map $\hat\phi:N\rightarrow M$; typically I think a condition might be that $M,N$ admit faithful normal states $\omega_M, \omega_N$ and then $\phi,\hat\phi$ should be related by, perhaps,
$$ \omega_N( a \phi(b) ) = \omega_M( \hat\phi(a) b) \qquad (a\in N, b\in M). $$

> I am interested in any literature references to this (or closely related) ideas.

I am certain I read a paper which did this: probably the paper had a mathematical physics motivation.  However, after some time browsing my downloaded paper collection, and on zbMath, I cannot find this.

I should add that in the situation I most care about, I can already prove the result I need.  So really I am after some links to the literature (as references, background reading etc.) and not sketch proofs.

Comment: Hi Matt. This looks like the Accardi-Ceccini adjoint. Gotta run but it's Prop 6.1 of \bibitem[AC]{AC}L. Accardi and C. Cecchini, \textit{Conditional expectations
in von Neumann algebras and a theorem of Takesaki, }J. Funct. Analysis 45
(1982), 245--273. Alternatively, Lemma 2.5 of \bibitem[AD]{AD}C. Anantharaman--Delaroche, \textit{On ergodic theorems for
free group actions on noncommutative spaces, }Probab. Theory Rel. Fields 135
(2006), 520--546.

Comment: @JonBannon: Yes, that's exactly the paper I had in mind!  Thanks!